# ImageView is not Clickable when clicked on it in android

Tags: android, layout, widget, onclick, imageview

I have 4 activities in my app, which are the menu items, if i click on 1st activity's menu all the items gets displayed, but on the second or the preceeding activities menu is not clickable and also menu items are not getting displayed, had given same coding for all activities but still i'm not getting the result. Here's my code for 2nd activity

```
public class About extends Activity {
LinearLayout line1, line2;
ImageView menu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
line1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
line2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);

menu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);

menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
  line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
 else { 
  line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
 } 
 }
});

      ImageView home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
      home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Home.class));
         }
          });

      ImageView jobs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jobs);
       jobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Jobs.class));
         }
          });

      ImageView log = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.log);
      log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Login.class));
         }
          });


      ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);
      about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(About.this, About.class));
         }
          });
```

xml code.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:src="@drawable/menu" />
  </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll2"
android:layout_width="199dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
android:visibility="gone"
>


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/about"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobs"
android:src="@drawable/about" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/jobs"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:src="@drawable/jobs" />

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/log"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:src="@drawable/log" />

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/home"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:src="@drawable/home" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is your imageview not clickable or no action is performing after the click ?

Comment: its not clickable for 2nd activity, for 1st activity it s clickable and displays the menu items @Pragnani

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to each of your ImageViews in the layout xml.